# Complex cypher query with deep and after filter

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have this graph:

[image: graph]

I'm trying to get all the nodes down that are inside an organizer and filter them under some conditions. The graph has few organizers but 10 million nodes and 20 million values.

The query is hanging on me. Someone shed a little light for me.

```
profile MATCH (os:`Organizer`) where id(os) = 70
WITH os 
OPTIONAL MATCH (os)<-[:`PARENT`*]-(o:`Organizer`)
WITH [o, os] AS orga UNWIND orga AS organizers 
MATCH (organizers)<-[:`CONTAINED`]-(a:Node)
with distinct a
MATCH (a)-[*0..]->(arr:Node)
with arr
MATCH (arr)-[:`DEFINED_BY`]->(t:`Template`) WHERE ((t:`tato` OR t:`tato` OR t:`System`) AND t.type = 'Complex' AND t.nemonic <> 'IDboxRTNumericContinuousSignalNemonic' AND t.nemonic <> 'IDboxRTNumericDiscreteSignalNemonic' AND t.nemonic <> 'IDboxRTNumericBinarySignalNemonic' AND t.nemonic <> 'IDboxRTStringSignalNemonic' AND t.nemonic <> 'IDboxRTAbstractNumericSignalNemonic' AND t.nemonic <> 'IDboxRTAbstractSignalNemonic') 

return count(arr)
```

I can't get both parts of the query to execute fast.

Comment: The relationships (e.,g., 'PARENT') should not be quoted. Does that change solve your hang? Are items indexed?

Comment: With quote work fine (neo4j 4.4). The nodes has Index at id property and other that i search. I think that the problem its cartesian product at inner match.... but i dont know why